# how can I do this the best way

Tags: xslt

I have a variable in xslt that must contains several values which depends on the page.
I know that `<xslt: variable>` cannot do the job because variables cannot be changed.

Can `xslt:param` does the job and how can I change it value on the fly?

Roelof

Edit 1 : I try to explain what I want. I have a website which displays articles per month. What I really like is a script where I can filter the articles so only the articles of a particular month is displayed in pages. But I need to decide how many articles are displayed on each page. So the number of displayed articles is based on the month and the displayed page.

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to use xslt in a programmatical way. Could you please post some sample of your input as well as your desired output? As it stands, your question cannot be reasonably answered I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT is a functional language**, which, among other things, means that an `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param`, once specified cannot change its value.

**This doesn't prevent the ability to express in XSLT the solution to any problem** (XSLT is Turing-complete) and only requires one to change thinking based on the imperative programming paradigm.

Once you publish your specific problem, many readers will be able to provide complete XSLT solutions.

**Here is a simple example**:

We "accumulate" all wanted values in a variable, then output it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOddsAccumulator">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vOddsAccumulator"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="num[. mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
01 03 05 07 09
```